# "app\Http\Controllers\" does not exist") laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I just want to echo Hello world through Route

```
Route::get('/user',[addnewcontroller::class, 'getData']);
```

this is my web.php Route
and this is controller

```
class addnewcontroller extends Controller
{
  function getData()
  {
     echo "My name is hassan";
  }
}
```

whenever i try to execute it say controller doesnt exist, kindly let me know why im facing this error, ive tried many things like clearing caches, code etc

Comment: can you show me routes file's imports?

Comment: <?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\addnewcontroller;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/user',[addnewcontroller::class, 'getData']);
?>

Comment: route file seems right. what about addnewcontroller class namespace?

Comment: namespace App\Http\Controllers;

Comment: use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Comment: what is the name of this controller file, what folder is it in? ... why does the error say `app\...` lowercase?

Comment: its in app\Http\Controllers\

Answer (score 0):

you need to define path of controller in **web.php**

like this:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\addnewcontroller;
```

Comment: its already defined

Comment: use App\Http\Controllers\addnewcontroller;

Answer (score 0):

You must `use App\Http\Controllers\addnewcontroller` at the top of routes

Comment: its already defined

Comment: Can you use capital first letter for class name?